# Как загрузить swagger-ui на сервер в интернете?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, api, swagger

Я создал API swagger на C#, смог выложить сайт на React с помощью сервиса netlify. Теперь хочу, чтобы моё API работало не только если я его запущу, а чтобы оно было на удаленном сервере, но не знаю как это сделать. Опишите подробно пожалуйста как мне это сделать(желательно бесплатный хостинг или с небольшой платой)

> program.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ShopAPI.Data;

var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {  
                          policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                              "http://www.contoso.com",
                                              "http://localhost:3000",
                                              "https://nitochkaigolochka.ml")
                          .AllowAnyHeader()
                          .WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "POST");
                      });
});

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ShopContext>(opt => {
    opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConection"));
});
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Пишете в поисковике "Asp.net хостинг", или можете арендовать VSD сервер, покупаете, смотрите как подключиться и как заливать. В проекте ПКМ - Опубликовать, выбираете нужные настройки (обычно просто в папку), полученные файлы заливаете на сервер, база если есть также, настраиваете/переносите. Все, готово.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами порекомендовать софт, библиотеку, хостинг не приветствуются на этом сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Собирай в [Docker'е](https://www.docker.com/) или ищи VDS с поддержкой [IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-web-server-overview)